# Django custom SQL returning single row of results when query returns 2?

Tags: sql, django

I have a custom SQL call that is returning different results to the template than I get when I run the same query against the database directly, 1 row vs 2

Query - copied from Django Debug Toolbar:

```
SELECT  ((Sum(new_recruit_interviews) / Sum(opportunities_offered)) * 100) as avg_recruit, ((Sum(inspections) / Sum(presentations)) * 100) as avg_inspect, ((Sum(contracts_signed) / Sum(roof_approvals)) * 100) as avg_contracts, ((Sum(adjusters) / Sum(contracts_signed)) * 100) as avg_adjusters, ((Sum(roof_approvals) / Sum(adjusters)) *100) as roof_approval_avg, ((Sum(roof_turned_in) / Sum(adjusters)) * 100) as roof_jobs_avg, Sum(roof_turned_in) as roof_jobs_total,
((Sum(siding_approvals) / Sum(adjusters)) *100) as siding_approval_avg, ((Sum(siding_turned_in) / Sum(adjusters)) * 100) as siding_jobs_avg, Sum(siding_turned_in) as siding_jobs_total, ((Sum(gutter_approvals) / Sum(adjusters)) *100) as gutter_approval_avg, ((Sum(gutter_turned_in) / Sum(adjusters)) * 100) as gutter_jobs_avg, Sum(gutter_turned_in) as gutter_jobs_total,
((Sum(window_approvals) / Sum(adjusters)) *100) as window_approval_avg, ((Sum(window_turned_in) / Sum(adjusters)) * 100) as window_jobs_avg, Sum(window_turned_in) as window_jobs_total,
(Sum(roof_turned_in) + Sum(siding_turned_in) + Sum(gutter_turned_in) + Sum(window_turned_in)) as total_jobs,
(((Sum(collections_jobs_new) + Sum(collections_jobs_previous)) / (Sum(roof_turned_in) + Sum(siding_turned_in) + Sum(gutter_turned_in) + Sum(window_turned_in))) * 100) as total_collections,
sales_report_salesmen.location_id as detail_id, business_unit_location.title as title
FROM sales_report_salesmen
Inner Join auth_user ON sales_report_salesmen.user_id = auth_user.id
Inner Join business_unit_location ON sales_report_salesmen.location_id = business_unit_location.id
GROUP BY location_id
```

Results from direct query running the above query:

```
INSERT INTO `` (`avg_recruit`, `avg_inspect`, `avg_contracts`, `avg_adjusters`, `roof_approval_avg`, `roof_jobs_avg`, `roof_jobs_total`, `siding_approval_avg`, `siding_jobs_avg`, `siding_jobs_total`, `gutter_approval_avg`, `gutter_jobs_avg`, `gutter_jobs_total`, `window_approval_avg`, `window_jobs_avg`, `window_jobs_total`, `total_jobs`, `total_collections`, `detail_id`, `title`)
   VALUES (95.3968, 92.8178, 106.9622, 90.2928, 103.5420, 103.5670, 4152, 100.2494, 106.8845, 4285, 120.1297, 86.2559, 3458, 92.9658, 106.1611, 4256, 16151, 4.281469, 12, 'St Paul, MN');

    VALUES (90.2982, 73.3723, 97.8474, 104.5433, 97.7585, 86.1848, 1884, 109.9268, 109.3321, 2390, 81.0156, 96.4318, 2108, 91.7200, 123.8792, 2708, 9090, 4.531573, 13, 'Denver, CO');
```

Results from template:

```
{'roof_jobs_total': Decimal('4152'), 'gutter_jobs_total': Decimal('3458'), 'avg_adjusters': Decimal('90.2928'), 'title': u'St Paul, MN', 'window_approval_avg': Decimal('92.9658'), 'total_collections': Decimal('4.281469'), 'gutter_approval_avg': Decimal('120.1297'), 'avg_recruit': Decimal('95.3968'), 'siding_approval_avg': Decimal('100.2494'), 'window_jobs_total': Decimal('4256'), 'detail_id': 12L, 'siding_jobs_avg': Decimal('106.8845'), 'avg_inspect': Decimal('92.8178'), 'roof_approval_avg': Decimal('103.5420'), 'roof_jobs_avg': Decimal('103.5670'), 'total_jobs': Decimal('16151'), 'window_jobs_avg': Decimal('106.1611'), 'avg_contracts': Decimal('106.9622'), 'gutter_jobs_avg': Decimal('86.2559'), 'siding_jobs_total': Decimal('4285')}
```

Tried tweaking it a few ways and running the results through various for loops, keep getting the same result where my results are a single row through the Django template and the expected results (through console) have 2 rows

The row that is coming back is the same as the first row returned through the console query so I'm thinking that it is running correctly just a matter of passing the results through...

for good measure this is the code I'm using to generate the query
(yes it's a bit ugly, been playing with it)

```
def sql_grouped(table, fields, group_by=False, where=False):
from django.db import connection
query = 'SELECT %s FROM %s' % (fields, table)
if where:
     query = query + ' WHERE %s' % (where)
if group_by:
    query = query + ' GROUP BY %s' % (group_by)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)

desc = cursor.description
data = [dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
return data[0]
```

any feedback is greatly appreciated - been tinkering with this since I realized I could skip a few steps by generating my averages directly within the SQL rather than post-process

Comment: Taking the glaring obvious out of the way: you sure you are connecting to the same database in both executions? You are not, by mistake, running Django against some test database other than the one you run the query manually, correct?

Comment: Yes this is against the same database, I was running this in multiple steps, pulling all data through a custom SQL using SUM(field) & group by - then creating the averages through a template tag row by row - worked great (IE all data correct) until I started working on sorting

Comment: Further details: If I take the math out of the SELECT fields and leave the Sum and GROUP BY then it correctly returns multiple rows - as it is the data is all correct but only the first row is returned

Comment: SOLVED!! Was overlooking some post processing that was limiting the return to only a single row - oddly necessary when working with cursor.execute() without the math present - made a mess of things - return data[0] was the culprit

Comment: Great! You might consider answering your own question so it doesn't show up as open for other SO users. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** - see comments above